# To which countries in Europe can I travel without a visa with a blue card from Bulgaria

Tags: europe, bulgaria, blue-card

I have a Bulgarian Blue Card, and I know that it is not valid for countries in the Schengen area. But, I can go, for example, to Romania (I was there last week) with the blue card.

There are others countries like Romania in Europe where I can go with my Blue Card for vacation?